# Telegram API позвонить человека с бота

Tags: api, telegram-bot

Всем привет, пытаюсь познать дзен telegram api. Необходимо, чтобы бот инициализировал звонок человеку, как это сделать?

Comment: звонки не поддерживаются https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586336/6131611 , но можно отправить голосовое сообщение https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice или аудио https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio

Comment: для начала определитесь, какой именно дзен взялись познавать - их два и новички постоянно их путают (_да, telegram api и telegram bot api разные вещи_)

Answer (score 1):

Бот звонки не может отправлять, это можно сделать либо с Client API, либо отправлять голосовые сообщения